# Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response with .net core and angular

Tags: angular, authentication, .net-core, cors, token

I am trying to send the request from one localhost:4200 (front) to localhost:xx (back). I am using angular 8 on the frontend and .net core 2.2 on the backend.

In the backend use in the startup:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
   options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
           builder => 
           builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowCredentials());
            });

app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc();
```

The problem start when integrate the auth with jwt and in angular set in interceptor the bearer and token:

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

For example doing it the request to the backend for login works, but after that get the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:1190/api/messagemapping'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Request header field authorization is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Greetings and thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot have `AllowAnyOrigin()` and `AllowCredentials()` at the same time. Either remove `AllowCredentials()`, or only allow specific origins.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i can ask why? i removed AllowCredentials and the problem fix!! wow a lot of thanks :D

Comment: If you're going to allow credentials to be passed, the server will need to know what domain(s) those credentials are good for.

Comment: Ouh! ok ok a lot of thanks!! have a nice day :).

How can mark your answer like 'the answer' of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Anwers was remove AllowCredentials() like @R. Richards said!