# Cors response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

I have tried multiple ways to rearrange the cors policy on the program.cs file. I have tried using other browsers however I keep getting the same error message. I am using .net 7 and Google Chrome with Angular front end.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddCors();

builder.Services.AddApplicationServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddIdentityServices(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => 
{
    opt.UseMySql("server=localhost; user=user; password=password; database=Database", 
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21)));
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();     

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseCors(builder => builder
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowCredentials()
.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", 
"https://localhost:4200"));

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");

using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
try
{
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<Role>>();
    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
    
    Seed.SeedRoles(context, roleManager);
    Seed.SeedUsers(context, userManager);
    Seed.SeedClientPreference(context);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var logger = services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during migration");
}

app.Run();

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddCors();

builder.Services.AddApplicationServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddIdentityServices(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => 
{
    opt.UseMySql("server=localhost; user=appuser; password=Password1; database=vitradapp", 
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21)));
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>(); // jwt ending token service


var app = builder.Build();





app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials()
    .WithOrigins());

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHttpsRedirection(); 


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");

using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
try
{
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<Role>>();
    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
    
    Seed.SeedRoles(context, roleManager);
    Seed.SeedUsers(context, userManager);
    Seed.SeedClientPreference(context);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var logger = services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred during migration");
}

app.Run();
```

Comment: I investigate the issue again, and using your backend code, not mine. Hope it could help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

You can remove `.AllowCredentials()` will fix the issue.

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    // Remove this line
    //.AllowCredentials()
    .WithOrigins());
```

Or

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowCredentials()
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200"));
```

[If you're going to allow credentials to be passed, the server will need to know what domain(s) those credentials are good for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923714/request-header-field-authorization-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-header)

---

The order of your middleware UseCors is wrong, so it didn't take effect. And I will show you the correct usage. You also can check the official doc: [Middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order)

The correct should be like below:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var  MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
          policy  =>
          {
              policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200",
                                          "https://localhost:4200");
          });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddApplicationServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddIdentityServices(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => 
{
    opt.UseMySql("server=localhost; user=user; password=password; database=Database", 
            new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21)));
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();     

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Fallback");
...
...
```

Comment: Just copied your code in and did it in that order, sadly im still getting that error message

Comment: could you share me details @GolfBravo

Comment: @GolfBravo Pls delete this repo, I have downloaded it. Tks, i will check it later and will update tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @GolfBravo, I have tested it, no cors issue. Since your nodejs project has some package issue in my side, and I test it via a new sample asp.net core application.

Comment: @GolfBravo Pls test in private mode in your browser. I believe my sample code is correct and I verify it again. Waiting for your update.

Comment: I've tried it in private mode but I'm still having the cors issue. Although now I know the backend works for you, It must be the angular front end causing this problem. During the weekend I'll have a look into what I have missed in Angular. It's version 10, so it may just need updating. Once I've done all that I'll let you know how I got on. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: if you can provide the angular sample which can run easily in my local by running “npm install” and “ng serve”. I am willing to check again. There are a lot of deprecated package in your previous project. @GolfBravo

Comment: Hi @GolfBravo, downloaded.

Comment: Hi @GolfBravo, share me angular/core, angular/cli,tsc, node, npm version.

Comment: I still can't run this project in my side, now the version in my side are : tsc -v 3.1.1,npm --version 6.14.6, ng --version Angular CLI: 7.3.8
Node: 14.6.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 10.0.14

Comment:  I am still working in this case. If you saw this message, you can share with me. @GolfBravo

Comment: tsc Version 4.9.5 
npm version 8.5.5
global angular 10.2.1
local version angular 10.0.6
node version 16.15.0
Windows 64 bit OS

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I will implement your solution in the next few days.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back. Angular stopped working as I updated it from angular 10 to 15. Now nothing works on Angular. There are many error messages. So I'm painfully going through them one by one and resolving them. It's sadly going to take a while before I'm back to the cors issue.

Comment: I've restored back to Angular 10 to get rid of the many error messages and back to .net 6, where I am using the startup.cs file. This resolved the Cors issue but it means I'm back to .Net 6.

Comment: I removed 
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 This has resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I removed the below

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Comment: I think that makes sense, in my sample code, I only used 'http://localhost:4200', so it worked in my test environment.

Comment: If you still using `policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200",
                                          "https://localhost:4200");` and `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`, only `https://localhost:4200` will take effect.

Comment: So the solution for this case should delete  `https://localhost:4200` in `WithOrigins`. And you also can according your requirement to enable or disable `UseHttpsRedirection` middleware.